Graph diameter bounds
I am trying to make sense of a proof of Theorem 1 below. Can someone help me understand the steps starting from the inequalities $>= k^m - ...$ ? I am not sure how that works?
The full paper is available at : https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-1989-0965008-X



We begin by splitting up the sum over all eigenvalues into the term for the first eigenvalue and the sum over all the rest. We have $\lambda_1^m (u_1 u_1^*)_{r,s} = k^m (vv^*)_{r,s}/n = k^m/n$, explaining how the inequality begins. For the other terms, the contribution could be positive or negative, so as a lower bound we subtract the absolute value of the sum. This shows that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^m (u_i u_i^*)_{r,s} \ge k^m/n - \left|\sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_i^m (u_i u_i^*)_{r,s}\right|.$$
Now we must work on bounding this sum. By the triangle inequality, we can distribute the absolute value over the summation. Each $|\lambda_i^m|$ we get is at most $|\lambda|^m$, which can then be factored out. We can write $(u_i u_i^*)_{r,s}$ as $(u_i)_r (u_i)_s$; this is just how matrix multiplication works. But how do we get an upper bound on $$\sum_{i=2}^n |(u_i)_r| |(u_i)_s|?$$
We can think of this as a dot product $xy^*$ of the two vectors $$x = (|(u_2)_r|, \dots, |(u_n)_r|), \qquad y = (|(u_2)_s|, \dots, |(u_n)_s|).$$ If $x$ also included the initial term $|(u_1)_r| = 1/\sqrt n$, then $x$ would (in absolute value) be the $r^{\text{th}}$ row of the orothogonal matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors; in particular, we would have $xx^*=1$. Without that first term, which contributes $|(u_1)_r|^2 = 1/n$, we have $xx^* = 1 - 1/n$ instead. Similarly, we have $yy^* = 1 - 1/n$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have $xy^* \le \sqrt{xx^* \cdot yy^*} = 1 - 1/n$. Therefore $$|\lambda|^m \sum_{i=2}^m \sum_{i=2}^n |(u_i)_r| |(u_i)_s| \le (1-1/n) |\lambda|^m$$ and we get a lower bound of $k^m/n - (1-1/n) |\lambda|^m$ on the whole sum.

I understood that the $k^m/n$ term comes from the contribution of the first eigenvalue and eigenvector, but I am not sure about the part of why we subtract all the i>1 terms' absolute values to get a lower bound on the rest of the contributions?

We don't know the signs of any of the other terms, so we want to prove that the result holds even if all the signs turn out to be negative. Subtracting the absolute values simulates that. Formally, we are using an $n$-term version of $x+y+z \ge x - |y|-|z|$, which follows from the triangle inequality $|x| \le |x + y + z| + |(-y)| + (-z)|$.
